# osm2psql: errors with default.style

Tags: windows, osm2pgsql

I'm using osm2psql to import some OSM data, but the default style file that comes packaged with the tool for Windows returns an error.

It seems to be expecting a differently formatted style file, but I can't seem to change it for it to work.

Command:

```
osm2pgsql -U *** -W *** -d *** -O flex -S D:\downloads\osm2pgsql-1.5.1-x64\osm2pgsql-bin\default.style south-america-latest.osm.pbf
```

Binary (1.5.1):
https://osm2pgsql.org/download/windows/

Data:
https://download.geofabrik.de/south-america.html

Error:

> ERROR: Error loading lua config:
> ...ownloads\osm2pgsql-1.5.1-x64\osm2pgsql-bin\default.style:2:
> unexpected symbol near '#'.

OS: Windows10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default style file is meant to be used with the `pgsql output`.

For the `flex output`, there is no default and you would have to provide your own `Lua` config file.

See the doc for the various [output](https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#the-outputs) type and more specifically for the new [`flex`](https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#the-flex-output) output type.

Comment: Thanks -- working with the psql output!